# Access denied while trying to terminate task manager

Tags: python, wmi, access-denied

```
for process in p.Win32_Process():
    print(f"{process.ProcessId:<10} {process.Name}")
    x = "taskmgr.exe"
    if str(x) in process.Name:
        time.sleep(1)
        while True:
            os.system(f'taskkill /f /im {x}')
    else:
        pass
```

When I try to terminate notepad I succeed and get the following message:

```
SUCCESS: The process "notepad.exe" with PID 17032 has been terminated.
```

But when I try to terminate Taskmgr.exe I get the following message

```
ERROR: The process "Taskmgr.exe" with PID 13256 could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.
```

I suppose this is happening because of some sort of security. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: try running the python script from a terminal with administrator rights...

Comment: Thanks, that worked.